# Like/Dislike Bar not working when updating

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax, css

I'm trying to integrate Like/Dislike Bar in a Wordpress plugin . It Works Properly when total page reload/refresh . But whentime Like/Dislike Bar refresh from ajax that time its not working .

**This is my html code .**

```
        <div class="progress">
                 <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                 <div class="bar bar-danger" style="width: 30%;"></div>
        </div>
```

**And this is my code in ajax for update**

```
$('.bar .bar-success').css('width','80%');
$('.bar .bar-danger').css('width', '20%');
```

but my like/dislike bar not updated .
Whats wrong in my code ?

Comment: '.$total_like_in_percent.' is not valid PHP, unless the entire HTML snippet is wrapped in a PHP string, where are the <?php ?> tags?

Comment: From what you've posted it isn't apparent what the problem is. What about [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)?

Comment: What is "like/dislike bar" for starters?